# Не показывает карту в приложении

Tags: ios, google-maps-api

Добрый день, в приложении есть раздел с картой GoogleMaps. Добавлял согласно документации. В консоли Google API создан ключ с ограничением на приложение iOS и прописан BundleId. Ключ назначается в AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("API_KEY")
    return true
}
```

Когда перехожу на экран с картой, в эту карту не подгружаются изображения карты.

В консоль улетает следующее:

```
Google Maps SDK for iOS cannot connect or validate APIKey: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" 
Your key may be invalid for your bundle ID: {идентификатор приложения, который указан в Google Console}
```

Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 2.3.30035.0

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы использовать Google Maps SDK на iOS необходимо помимо получения ключа активировать сам API а консоли. Для этого идем в консоль [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com), заходим в раздел "Библиотека", выбираем Google Maps SDK for iOS и нажимаем кнопку "Включить". Теперь, если у вас есть ключ и прописан идентификатор пакетов, карта отобразится.

Возможно я слеп и не увидел это в руководстве по внедрению.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, я просто головой бился об стену, потому что карта в iOS приложении не отображалась а в android приложении отображалась. И ведь ни где не сказано об этом ни слова, что в панели управления API нужно включать отдельно для iOS. В общем 100500 плюсов летит вам в карму!